# Doxygen is confusing a project file with a system library file with the same name

Tags: c, doxygen

I have a large C project, with multiple directories and subdirectories, that I'm trying to document with Doxygen version 1.7.6.1-2ubuntu1.

My problem is that the project has a file (`string.h`) which Doxygen is confusing with the system library include file of the same name.  In the project code, the project file is included with `#include "lib/string.h"` and the system file is included with `#include <string.h>`.

However Doxygen always references the project include file, regardless of which of the two `#include` forms is used.  (And since the project `string.h` happens to include the system `string.h`, Doxygen actually shows a self-referential dependency in the dependency graph!)

How can I configure Doxygen to take notice of whether `#include "..."` or `#include <...>` has been used, and not match the project file in the latter case?  It's not a practical proposition to rename the project file and change all of the other files that use it.

Comment: My advice is to file a bug report with a suggested feature request and in the future don't use such names. Were it not large, I'd say do the include graph yourself in the source code comments that Doxygen parses and disable the INCLUDE_GRAPH generation. (Maybe combine this approach with EXCLUDE?) Alternatively, find a different documentation generation system or build your own... You can document outside the code as well as a minor bit in the code. I believe LLVM took this approach when it chose RST files and Sphinx. Either way, more work, but more flexibility!

Comment: Well, it looks like nobody else has any suggestions :)  Thanks for the information though.  I'll dig into the Doxygen source and see how hard it will be to make Doxygen recognise bracketed includes, and treat them all as "unknown" files that should not be matched to any project files.  If I can get it to work I'll consider making it configurable and submitting it as an upstream patch.